# nodemon,jest,installation error,versions,console-log

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jestjs, web-development-server

I am attempting to install jest and nodemon for my nodejs project, I am using vscode, npm version 6.13.7, and node version 13.8.0. When I attempt to install nodemon through the command line, I get the following console log...

```
 npm install nodemon --save-dev

> deasync@0.1.14 install C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync
> node ./build.js


C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an 
error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used        
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used        
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an 
error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)    
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON    
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)    
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)    
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mickell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v13.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN cryptochain@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN cryptochain@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} 
(current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! deasync@0.1.14 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-27T05_58_06_796Z-debug.log
```

when installing jest, I get the following console error log...

```
$ npm i jest --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or 
migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).

> deasync@0.1.14 install C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync
> node ./build.js


C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an 
error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used        
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used        
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an 
error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)    
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON    
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)    
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mickell\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v13.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN cryptochain@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN cryptochain@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! deasync@0.1.14 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mickell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-27T06_04_25_295Z-debug.log
```

there is one part of both console error logs that I have suspicions on, and that is "gyp ERR! cwd C:\cypher_network\node_modules\deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v13.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed" I hope maybe this narrowed down the problem, thanks!
I

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Python: https://realpython.com/installing-python/ or https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Package dependencies in your project are using [node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) to build themselves for your operating system on install, and that requires Python. See the link to node-gyp for more details.

It is the [deasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deasync) package that you are relying on that is doing this. It is written in C++. You are either directly requiring `deasync`, or it is a transitive dependency of some other package you are requiring.

Comment: My previous projects have no problem when it comes to installing jest or nodemon, also this is a js project. I will give it a try but I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: It literally says it can't find Python. It is needed for some npm package build tasks in your dependencies that use `node-gyp`.

Comment: I downloaded python and it is still giving me the same error message.